Why can't I see my Volume from every angle?
Why am I unable to see my Volume object from every angle within my grease pencil scene?

I tried checking In Front for the volume and deselecting In Front for the grease pencil object.
I tried moving the volume up in the outliner.
I tried adjusting the volume itself in density and displacement.
I made sure it was visible in the Outliner.


I noticed that when I turn off the visibility of the grease pencil background I am able to see the volume from all angles. That lead me to think the grease pencil was set to show in front but it was not.
I am using Blender 4.2 and I'm trying to use this feature to create a smoke-like chalk dust effect in my animation.
The pictures are from different times. But I still face the same issue.

Is it possible the material is blocking it?
